# A SQL only runs slow in a psycopg2 / PostgreSQLcode

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I had a PostgreSQL for IoT applications. There are many IoT timeseries data in one table, called events. Since it contains too many rows, about 800M rows. The SQL query of this table returns very slow. I delete most of the rows, at this moment it contains only 9K rows. **UPDATE: its size expands to 500K in the next day.** I can test the SQL response time from a cloud console from AliCloud/RDS, most of them can return within 2ms.

However, I found one of my psycopg2 code of querying this table still return very slow, longer than 60 seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding: utf-8
import psycopg2
import time
import sys


# Take care the connection params
def main():
    conn = None
    try:
        host = "pgm-myaddress.rds.aliyuncs.com"
        port = 1921
        #'''
        account = "mypgserver"
        password = "mypasswd"
        database = "mytestdb"

        connect_timeout = 10
        options = "-c DateStyle="
        conn = psycopg2.connect(host = host,
                                port = port,
                                user = account,
                                password = password,
                                database = database,
                                connect_timeout = connect_timeout,
                                options = options)

        conn.autocommit = True
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        _start = time.time()
        # Take care the quotation marks
        eui64 = "EC1BBDFFFE29011F"
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM controllers WHERE guid = %s LIMIT 1", [eui64])
        if result is not None:
            controllerId = result[0]
            print(result)
            print("Controller_ID: {}".format(controllerId))
            _elapsed = time.time() - _start
            print("SQL_1 Elapsed:{}\r\n".format(_elapsed))
        else:
            print("SQL_1:None\r\n")
            sys.exit(0)

        _start = time.time()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE fk_controller = %s LIMIT 1", [controllerId])
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        deviceId = result[0]
        print(result)
        print("Device_ID: {}".format(deviceId))
        _elapsed = time.time() - _start
        print("SQL_2 Elapsed:{}\r\n".format(_elapsed))

        _start = time.time()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM events ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 100")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Count = {}".format(len(result)))
        _elapsed = time.time() - _start
        print("Elapsed = {}\r\n".format(_elapsed))

        _start = time.time()
        controllerId = 1108
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM events WHERE fk_controller = %s ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 20", [controllerId])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Count = {}".format(len(result)))
        for res in result:
            print("Event : {}".format(res))
        _elapsed = time.time() - _start
        print("Elapsed = {}\r\n".format(_elapsed))

        _start = time.time()
        deviceId = 1012
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM events WHERE fk_device = %s ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 20", [deviceId])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Count = {}".format(len(result)))
        for res in result:
            print("Event : {}".format(res))
        _elapsed = time.time() - _start
        print("Elapsed = {}\r\n".format(_elapsed))

        _start = time.time()
        deviceId = 1012
        cursor.execute("EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM events WHERE fk_device = %s ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 20", [deviceId])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Explain: {}".format(result))
        _elapsed = time.time() - _start
        print("Elapsed = {}\r\n".format(_elapsed))

        _start = time.time()
        deviceId = 1012
        cursor.execute("EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM events WHERE fk_device = %s LIMIT 20", [deviceId])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Explain: {}".format(result))
        _elapsed = time.time() - _start
        print("Elapsed = {}\r\n".format(_elapsed))


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then I got the following result:

```
SQL_1:0.0015239715576171875
(1212, 1, 1, None, 5, 'EC1BBDFFFE29075A', 'EC1BBDFFFE29075A', '68e1437b-f0da-4615-a934-1790012e6dba', '2.2.0', 21, 42842, 42942, '0', 'C01_9884e3072fbd', '6241902e', datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 8, 23, 12, 56, 363467, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 23, 13, 40, 17, 947000, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 23, 13, 40, 18, 884370, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 8, 23, 12, 56, 806480, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)), None)
Controller_ID: 1212

SQL_2:0.0009047985076904297
(1108, 1, 1, None, 1212, 8, 'sensors', 'EC1BBDFFFE29075A', 'EC1BBDFFFE29075A', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), '', {}, {}, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 23, 13, 40, 19, 628069, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 23, 13, 40, 19, 628069, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 23, 13, 40, 19, 628069, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 23, 13, 40, 19, 628069, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)), None)
Device_ID: 1108

Count = 5
Elapsed = 31.72335386276245

Explain: [('Limit  (cost=0.42..432.80 rows=20 width=136) (actual time=0.013..0.050 rows=20 loops=1)',), ('  ->  Index Scan Backward using events_pkey on events  (cost=0.42..1885205.89 rows=87202 width=136) (actual time=0.012..0.046 rows=20 loops=1)',), ('        Filter: (fk_device = 1012)',), ('        Rows Removed by Filter: 111',), ('Planning Time: 0.062 ms',), ('Execution Time: 0.065 ms',)]
Elapsed = 0.001512765884399414

Explain: [('Limit  (cost=0.00..427.41 rows=20 width=136) (actual time=72971.667..72971.730 rows=20 loops=1)',), ('  ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..1863543.06 rows=87202 width=136) (actual time=72971.666..72971.724 rows=20 loops=1)',), ('        Filter: (fk_device = 1012)',), ('        Rows Removed by Filter: 224',), ('Planning Time: 0.035 ms',), ('Execution Time: 72971.750 ms',)]
Elapsed = 72.97247743606567
```

The first two SQL return within 2ms, but the latest one returns longer than 31 seconds. I tested the latest SQL in Alicloud's console, only 50ms.

**UPDATE**

I find that the performance is related to the "ORDER BY id DESC" in the query. We can find out that query without "ORDER BY id" will start Seq Scan, aka one by one sequential scan. The query orderd by id will start Index Scan over events_pkey primary key, which is much faster than sequential scan.

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM \"devices\" WHERE fk_controller = {} LIMIT 1".format(controllerId))` <<-- bad style.

Comment: 1) Only one query runs slow in `psycopg2`, not ' I found my psycopg2 code still return very slow.' 2) The first two query run in 1.5 ms and 0.9 ms, so they run in less then 2 ms. 3) Take out the `print()` lines between `_start = time.time()` and `_elapsed = time.time() - _start` so it is like you have in the other examples. 4) Look in the Postgres log and see what form the query  is in when it hits the database.

Comment: Whenever you are asking about query performance, make sure to post the results of [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html). And also, learn about [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your comments. I have updated my question as well as the code. I agree print() will add extra overhead, now it return time is reduced to 30s after removal them. But I will ask help from Alicloud helpdesk for logging. All I can do is try to use explain.

Comment: Not just EXPLAIN, use something like EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to really execute the query and see where things are slow. Using just EXPLAIN, will just give you the query plan and that's it and will not show anything about performance.

Comment: You still have a `print` between the `_start` and the `_elapsed`. I don't think it will make a huge difference, but it does mean that sequence is not the same as the others. Also as mentioned by @wildplasser, `....format(controllerId)` is bad. You are not actually using the `controllerId` so it should not be included. Besides this is not the proper way to pass parameters. To see what is go to [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: @wildplasser I have updated my code.

Comment: There are many comments about my query strings. Then I read the document, and update the code. However it is not the bottleneck. My first update doesn't help. Yesterday (20220421) I tried to change my code again, then the new query runs extremely fast. Then I compared the versions, I found that the performance is improved because I added "ORDER BY id DESC". With order parameter, it scans over pkey index, Otherwise it scans seq one by one. The root cause also is proved by EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Thanks everyone!  *** Now I will update the question and close it.